# Need to find totals for Resource Group Spend based on Cost Management API

Tags: powershell, export-to-excel

I have managed to export an xlsx file that has 2 columns based on a list of amount spent on each Resource Group based on a daily basis over a 30 day period but what I know need to do now is for each Resource Group create a total based on the 30 entries.

I have been looking at this link ([Using Powershell, how can I sum the values in an excel column and sort by the value of another variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54576574/using-powershell-how-can-i-sum-the-values-in-an-excel-column-and-sort-by-the-va)) that is close to what I am trying to do but I am fairly new to doing this type of Powershell.

I only have 2 columns with headers of "Spend" and "Resource Group" so was wondering if someone could help me get the totals out from just two columns because the $product part is throwing me off.

Comment: It would help us if you included an example of your file data; what you are currently using and any specific errors/issues you are getting with your current method :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your excel file is named **excel.xlsx** with each row representing a total day spend per resource group and you have installed the **ImportExcel** module, you can do the following:

```
$data = Import-Excel excel.xlsx
$data | Group-Object "Resource Group" |
    Select-Object @{n='Resource Group';e={$_.Name}},
        @{n='Total Spend';e={($_.Group.Spend | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum}}
```

Your result will be an object with properties/columns called `Resource Group` and `Total Spend`. You can rename them however you wish.

Comment: This appears to have worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help